# when i rotate a face it rotates the entire thing

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

when i rotate a face it rotates the entire thing so like when i want to rote the face it rotates the rest of the mesh, i just want to rotate that singular mesh i am following a tutorial by tech guru (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBtDix7xGOg) and about the 2:35 mark he rotates a face but when i do it it rotates the entire mesh

[image: first picture]

[image]

but i want it to look like this

[image]

entire screen[image]

(entire screen)

Comment: Proportional editing is on (see last screenshot: blue circles in the middle of the top bar)

Comment: THANK YOU! it finally works